# How to share hotspot through SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I'm connected to a LAN, and want to provide a hotspot for a mobile phone.
Further, all the phones content should be served through a `ssh socks5` tunnel, which is running with:

`sshpass -p <pass> ssh -Nf -D 8090 user@domain.com`

Questin: what could I do now to route all hotspot wlan traffic directly to port `8090` of the ssh socket?

I tried the solution here: [How to share WiFi/hotspot over SSH tunnel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514592/how-to-share-wifi-hotspot-over-ssh-tunnel)

BUT: when trying to add the iptables commands, nothing happens. No iptable routes are added at all.
Any solution would be fine. Also installing additional tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it works just as that. I didn't notice I have to check the rule specifying the table explicit:

`iptables -t nat -L`